# manejar cuanta memoria se usa en kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, grub2

Desde hace vario tiempo tengo un problema con mi pc y es que no puedo usar toda mi memoria ram por completo, busque en varios foros y busque información sobre esto por Internet y no pude llegar a una conclusión, el problema es que tengo una memoria ram de 2GB y otra de 4GB, cuando entro a opciones de arranque en windows (msconfig) puedo regular cuanta memoria usa mi pc, por lo general no me deja usar mas de 4096GB (2048 x 2), me deja usar solamente 2GB de cada una, si en la configuración aumento a mas de 4096GB osea 4097 para arriba, cuando reinicio la pc se crashea, directamente no me deja ingresar al OS, es un problema para mi grave por que como saben la ram es indispensable a la hora de procesar datos en la programación y estoy trabajando en un proyecto grande, me acostumbre a usarla asi, lo que estoy buscando ahora es poder hacer esta misma configuración en kali linux, estoy tratando de que solamente kali use 4096GB de ram, en windows entro a msconfig y lo soluciono desde ahí, pero en este caso quiero hacerlo con kali linux, gracias por su tiempo y espero puedan ayudarme con este problema que tengo hace mucho tiempo

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no se ajusta a [ask]

Comment: pude por fin encontrar una solucion a un problema que tengo hace mucho, deja que pueda solucionarlo y luego vota por cerrarla

Comment: ¿Tú PC acepta esa combinación de memorias en la placa madre? Tengo Linux Mint con 12 GB corriendo sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes limitar la memoria disponible para el sistema des del arranque de GRUB.
Para eso tienes que añadir el parámetro `mem=4096m`
en el fichero `/etc/default/grub`. Resptea los existentes.

```
# these options get added to both standard and recovery boot entries
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="var1 var2 mem=1024m"
```

Una vez guardado los cambios del fichero, dile al sistema que rehaga la configuracion del grub con la comanda `sudo update-grub`

Comment: que es lo que hace tu sugerencia? el var1 y el var2 que es lo que hacen ?

Comment: Nada, forman parte del <Respeta los existentes>

Comment: osea que se pueden omitir tranquilamente y solamente typear mem=4096m ?

Comment: Si, respetando los que ya existan en tu fichero